# Definition of the function space $C^{\alpha,\beta}(\Omega\times [0,T])$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation, holder-spaces

I saw the space $C^{\alpha,\beta}(\Omega\times [0,T])$, with $\alpha, \beta>0$. I do not know what this means. For the context, I infer that this should be a Hölder Space in the time and space but, if this is the case, how is the norm in this space? Where I can read more about this space?

Comment: Where did you see this notation? Can you include the source? Commonly used in PDE; it should be clearly under context what it means. Here is a common one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition#H%C3%B6lder_spaces

Comment: In the paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314300243_Boundedness_and_stabilization_in_a_two-dimensional_two-species_chemotaxis-Navier-Stokes_system_with_competitive_kinetics Lema 4.6

Comment: Hmm, if you look at the proof of Lemma 4.6, it seems that $\alpha$ is the Holder exponent for the space component while $\beta$ is for the time component. It seems that the authors do not define it explicitly. The safest way to decipher such notation could be (1) write to the authors and ask; (2) check the papers in the references; (3)look at the place where the notation is actually used, which should give a hint of its meaning.